# Calculating the cost for each operation in amortized analysis

Tags: amortized-analysis

According to what I've read in the CLRS book , we calculate the amortized cost for a complete set , and not for a single operation.But in an exam question , it was asked about an operation amortized cost and there hadn't been any info on the analyze function.

In these scenarios, how would one calculate the cost for an operation?
For example , In the fibonacci heap , the extraction cost is considered.
Is there any standard for this or is the exam question wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: They might have been asking about aggregate analysis, which is discussed at the beginning of Chapter 17 of CLRS 3rd ed. In aggregate analysis, you show that a sequence of operations takes worst case time T(N), and then you can say that on average, the cost of a single operation in a set of n operations is T(N) / n.